# When are attacks/defenses no long able to be shared

Tags: clash-of-clans

For example, assume my attack and defense log is full and I am still in my current season (about mid-way). Some of my attacks/defenses are still able to be shared with my clan while others cannot be shared. This excludes attacks/defenses that can be replayed by me but cannot be shared with the clan.

What would cause an attack or a defense to no longer be able to be shared? All I know that only the first four attacks and defenses can be shared and that a new season causes every attack and defense (from last season) to be no longer shareable nor viewable.

This is not a duplicate as I am asking of all the requirements that must be met to become unshareable only.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few reasons why you cannot share some replays. As you mentioned, only the last 4 attack/defense replays in your log may be shared, all older ones are unsharable, after updates (maintenance breaks), any replays for attacks made before the patch are unsharable/unwatchable, and after the season  ends, and replays from attacks in the previous season are also unsharable/unwatchable. Also, if you have shared a replay in the last 30 minutes, you will not be able to share another replay until 30 minutes from the time you shared the replay has passed.